# Are there any "distinguished" points in the category of smooth manifolds?

Tags: category-theory, differential-topology, functors

Consider the category of smooth manifolds $\mathcal{M}$ with the morphisms being the smooth maps. Consider the category of manifolds with a distinguished point $\mathcal{M}_o.$ The objects of  $\mathcal{M}_o$ are ordered pairs $(M,x)$ such that $ x \in M$ and morphisms between $(M_1,x)$ and $(M_2,y)$ are smooth maps $f:M_1 \to M_2$ such that $ f(x)=y.$

**Is it true that there are no functors $F$ from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{M}_o$ such that $$ F(M)=(M,x)$$ for some $x \in M?$**

Comment: Hint: consider the smooth map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x+1$.

Comment: In fact, the singleton is the *only* smooth manifold with a distinguished point. The automorphism group of *every* other smooth manifold has no fixed points.